# How is Tabstrip different from Multipage in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Could someone please explain, how "Multipage" is different from "TabStrip" ?

I am confused about the usage of TabStrip and multipage in Visual Basic...

Comment: Put a control on a MultiPage tab and that control becomes a child of that Tab and will hide/show as needed when other tabs are selected.  A TabStrip does not do this and requires you manage that stuff yourself.

Comment: Hi Alex,  Thanks for explaining.  I understood it now.   Sorry for the delayed response.